# Can we say "He drunk water?"

Tags: verbs, word-usage

I know about the comparatives - drink,drank,drunk. But when I just used it in the sentence
"He drunk water!", Someone pointed that it was wrong and that the verb "DRUNK" must be used only when someone is intoxicated like "He was drunk!". Is this right? Can anyone clarify this?

Comment: **Did you mean:** _He was drunk from water?_

Comment: Comparatives? No, _drink_ is a verb, not an adjective. _Drink/drank/drunk_ are verb forms (often called ‘tenses’ for simplicity, though really only one of them is a true tense). The only comparative you could make would be _more drunk_, which is the comparative of the adjective _drunk_. Since you both mislabelled and misused the verbal forms, I would not be so fast to claim that you “know about” them…

Comment: I am sorry, I didn't know how to describe the verbs, that's why I used comparatives.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"He **drunk** water" is not correct grammatically.It should be "he **drank** water".That is said the word [drunk](https://www.google.com/search?q=drunk&oq=drunk&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60.3205j0j4&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8) refers to one's physical and mental faculties are impaired by an excess of alcoholic drink.However we can imagine sentences where [drunk](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=1710580) is used without implying alcohol consumption.For example:

Drink - drank - drunk
Drink is the present: I like to drink coffee.
Drank is the simple past: I drank coffee yesterday.
Drunk is the past participle used for the present perfect and past perfect: I have never drunk coffee, I had never drunk coffee.

Comment: Why not "drunk water?". I still don't get it!

Comment: It's for the same reason you can't say *"I written the book"*.  You need to either say *"I wrote the book"* or *"I've written the book."* (*write/wrote/written*) Similarly, you either have to say *"I drank the water"* or *"I've drunk the water"*. (*drink/drank/drunk*)

Comment: Now, that's the explanation I can agree to! Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

The verb "drunk" is not only used when someone is intoxicated but is also a participle of "drink", so that person was incorrect. Also in the form of intoxication it wouldn't even be a verb.
Though the correct sentence would be either "He drank water" or "He has drunk water".
Drink, Drank, Drunk.

Comment: That's what even I thought of, but some people like the one above won't agree!So, I don't know which one is right!

Comment: From what I understand @sojourner does agree? "I drink water", "I drank water", "I have drunk water" are all correct sentences. More info here: http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/drink?s=t